# Access token to view likes on a page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

It's not clear in the documentation how you can access the likes of a page. I know i can access my likes easily, but a client of mine would like us to be able to read all the likes each 5 minutes for example and detect who is the 2000th liker.

The problem is that i can't even seem to understand how to get an access token to a specific page.

My understanding although still very obscure to me would be that i need to create an app that asks for this user to authenticate as the page and authorize the app to get the likes of that page?

Am i right?

When responding, can you please provide a basic code base to understand how to do it, i've done 1 facebook login so far and it was hell...

Thanks

---

**UPDATE**

Important, when i'm talking about a page, i'm talking about a facebook page, not an external page on the web. The exact page i'm looking to get the likes from is:

http://www.facebook.com/starfrit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getting the actual like for any given page is easy, but you cant find out which user gave them. (or in which order)

```
$result = $facebook->api(array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => 'select fan_count from page where page_id = 140812822635148;'
));
```

or without api:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/140812822635148
```

or for an external url:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.redbull.com
```

Comment: But there is still no way to get the list as i understand it, it wasn't just a misunderstanding... thanks anyway

Comment: right, you cant find the person which for e.g. gave the 1000th like.